# Host key verification failed when using supervisorctl to git pull

Tags: git, ssh, supervisord

The git config is:
`url = ssh://a.b.com:port/d1/d2`

I write a python script `g.py` to `git pull`, it works fine when I just execute it by `python3 g.py`. However, if I execute this python file in supervisorctl, there is a error `Host key verification failed`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that `supervisorctl` won't execute your script as the same user as you did when you ran the python script `g.py`.

That means it won't have the same `~/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)` key files.
As a test, try to copy those files in `/root/.ssh`, and see if that work better.

The OP confirms that [`url.<base>.insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) are in the *user* global config (`/home/auser/.gitconfig`), which would not been used by `supervisorctl` (running as `root`).
Moving those directives in the local config (`/path/to/repo/.git/config`) would help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have such files in `~/.ssh/`

Comment: Do you have any file in that folder?

Comment: Where is your python script looking for your private SSH key?

Comment: If I use command line, I use `cd` to go to the directory and use `git pull`, and it works fine.  My python script is using `GitPython` library, it works fine too if I run `python3 g.py`, but it doesn't work when I supervisorctl  on `python3 g.py`

Comment: @user6456568 And `git remote -v` in that directory does show the ssh url you mention?

Comment: @use but... That is not an SSH URL though. It it an https one.

Comment: So why the error exists`git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(1)
  cmdline: git pull
  stderr: 'Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.'
`

Comment: @user6456568 May be because it does not use origin? Where does `url = ssh://a.b.com:port/d1/d2` come from? If git remote -v shows an https URL, do you see it in that same git config? You can do a `git config --show-origin -l`

Comment: there is some lines that `url.https//xxxx.com/a.insteadof=ssh://a.b.com:port`

Comment: with `git config --show-origin -l`, can you see in which config file that insteadof directive is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185186/discussion-between-user6456568-and-vonc).

Comment: @user6456568 supervisorctl is running as root: it does not have access to the /home/xxx/.gitconfig global config, so it does not use insteadof directives and its HTTPS URL. It only uses the /path/to/repo/.git/config local config, and its SSH URL. Hence the error message. I have edited the answer accordingly.